# Close hover div only when clicked outside block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have got a loginbox (blue) that opens when you hover over the text login (Yellow). The box stays open when you go to the loginbox but it closes when you leave it (Mouse in the green area).

This is expected behaviour with my current css (using hover and display:none / block)

I would like the loginbox (blue) to stay open even when you enter the green area. But when you click in the green area the loginbox (blue) closes (display: none)

I guess this is only possible with javascript/jQuery but I have no idea how. Can anyone help me with this?

Don't worry about div id's and classes. I will change the code to my needs.

[image]

Comment: If you allow and ask for a jQuery based solution, you will get a lot of help very quickly.

Comment: I have no problem with jQuery

Comment: can you post you sample code?

Comment: This look like a `Do this for me` question

Comment: @WingLeong Probably this is the case, but he made an effort to post a clear and specific question that deals with a commonly requested design feature.  Worthy of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/gnyyB/

```
$('#main').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#menu').show();
});

// To prevent hide #menu when click on #main
$('#main').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

// Click outsite of #menu
$('html').click(function () {
    $('#menu').hide();
});
```

Comment: You might want to explain why `e.stopPropagation()` is needed and also why attach the click-to-hide action to `html` instead of `body`.  The OP is not a JavaScript/jQuery expert.

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` is to prevent hide `#menu` when click on `#main`, `html` and `body` should also work, up to u

Comment: The reason I mention the `html` and `body` tag is related to a quirk in jsFiddle.  The extent of the body element is less than that of the root (html), so the demo works better when binding to the html element.  When binding to the body element, you need to click on the line containing the content to activate the action.

Comment: Oh, strange, I don't know why O3O

Comment: +1 for the jQuery, works well.  Please update your answer based on the comments, it will make it more user friendly.  All the best.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I bound it not to html but to the wrapper. worked just as good in my case. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
   function example(){  

   var divId = document.getElementById("divId");

   divId.style.display = "block";

  }
```

Here `divId` is the blue color divId and call this function in `onhover` for green div.

Comment: Then the blue block stays open. I would like it to be closed when clicked in the green area. The blue box should also only be opened when the yellow box is hovered

Comment: then call another function in div click